# Selecting the current element in a div

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a div that has `contenteditable` set to true. I need to add a class to the `<p>` element that the user is on. The problem is that `contenteditable` generates a lot of `<p>` elements when written in. How do I add the class only to the `<p>` element that the user is on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Need to provide some code so we know where to start, also try to provide any different methods you've tried.

Comment: With that being said, you could use CSS and use #div:active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use [selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).

This code will give you element where caret is:

```
var selObj = window.getSelection(); 
var element = selObj.focusNode.parentElement;
```

And now it is up to you what to do with that element.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below approach should work -

HTML

```
<html>
  <div class="div1" contenteditable=true>
    Div1
  </div>
</html>
```

JS

```
document.onkeyup = 
function addClassOnElem(e)
{
  alert(e.target)
  //get the current element or parents here
  e.target.className = "div2"
}
```

Comment: What if selection was made by mouse?